Laravel 11 API no recibe las cookies de mi cliente VueJS
No puedo realizar solicitudes que requieran autorización a mi API. Aunque tengo la cookie seteada en el navegador, la misma parece no estarse enviando.
Estoy intentando hacer una solicitud de prueba a /api/user (que usa el middleware auth:sanctum) y recibo 401 debido a este problema con la cookie
Backend Laravel 11
Http/Controllers/GithubAuthController.php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

class GithubAuthController extends Controller
{
    // api/auth/github
    public function redirectToGithub()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('github')->stateless()->redirect();
    }

    // api/auth/github/callback
    public function handleGithubCallback()
    {
        // Get the authenticated user
        $githubUser = Socialite::driver('github')->stateless()->user();

        // Logic for user creation and token generation goes here
        $user = User::firstOrCreate([
            'github_id' => $githubUser->getId(),
        ], [
            'name' => $githubUser->getName(),
            'nickname' => $githubUser->getNickname(),
            'email' => $githubUser->getEmail(),
            'avatar' => $githubUser->getAvatar(),
            'password' => Hash::make(Str::random(12))
        ]);

        // Generate API token & cookie
        $token = $user->createToken('github-auth-token')->plainTextToken;

        $cookie = cookie(
            $name ='auth',
            $token,
            $minutes = 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
        );
        
        return response()
                ->redirectTo('http://localhost:5173/miapp/')
                ->withCookie($cookie);
    }
}

config/cors.php
<?php

return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:5173'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];

Frontend: VueJS
src/components/SignInButton.vue
<script setup>

const signInUrl = `${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/api/auth/github`;
function loginWithGithub() {
      window.location.href = signInUrl;
    }
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="loginWithGithub">Sign In with GitHub</button>
</template>

src/components/Navbar.vue
<script setup>
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router'
import SignInButton from './SignInButton.vue';
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';

const user = ref(null)

const apiRequest = async (endpoint) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/${endpoint}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          },
          credentials: 'include'
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorData = await response.json();
            throw new Error(errorData.message || 'Error en la solicitud');
        }

        return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

onMounted(async () => {
  user.value = await apiRequest('user');
});
</script>
<template>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li v-if="!user">
        <SignInButton />
      </li>
      <li v-if="user">
        <span>Hi!, {{ user.name }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>

La cookie se establece en el navegador pero no se envía
He intentado hacer requests de varias formas, de hecho haciendolo desde postman con el header 'Authorization' funciona bastante bien
